# Can't ssh into Amazon AWS from Office CentOS

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, cygwin

I have Windows and using cygwin.

I have an Amazon Ubuntu instance I can log in just fine from my system using

ssh  -i keyfile \ username@AmazonHost.

However when I ssh to a CentOS server I have at my office and try to SSH to the Amazon instance from there using the same commands I always get a public key error.   I have copied my keyfile over and set permissions to chmod 400 just like I did on my Cygwin client.   Also on the CentOS I verified I can access the amazon instance over port 22(telnet AmazonHost 22).

Is there some other configuration on the CentOS or Office firewall that needs to be done to allow me to connect to Amazon?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a public key error on one machine and not the other, then the two secret keys are different, even though you think they are the same. (Unless one machine's ssh client is totally broken.)

The file might have been corrupted in transit, but since one of the machines is Windows (though with Cygwin) and the other is Linux, my guess is that something went wrong with line endings when the key was copied from one to the other. The keys are usually encoded as text (that's how Amazon's console does it), and are fairly immune to line ending changes, but this seems to be a possible cause.

How did you transfer the file from one machine to the other? If you can adjust it, try the transfer once in binary mode and once in text mode, to see if either works. Also, just look at the files on each machine in a text editor. Do they look the same?

Comment: I used Scp to transfer the file u believe with winscp. Ill look at the key files and see if there's a difference